# Cefsharp webbrowser send input

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio, getelementbyid, cefsharp

I want to be able to simulate a click or keyboard input to a web element in my cefsharp (chromium) webbrowser.

Lets say I want to type "stack overflow," for instance, into the google searchbox. I want to be able to simulate that keyboard input into the google search box web element so that the search box says "stack overflow" and it would act as if a human typed "stack overflow."

**Research:** I have found out ways to do this (untested) in the visual studio web element, but not chromium. For reference, the code I found is `browser.Document.GetElementById('web element').InvokeMember("Click")` however, I do not know if or how this works.

I have also found the `ExecuteScriptAsync` function, but I am not sure how to use it. **I am pretty sure I need to use executescriptasync**, but I am not sure what parameters I would use.

**My Setup:**
I am using visual basic, visual studio, and the cefsharp chromium-based web browser

**The Question:** To reiterate, I would like to be able to simulate keypresses and mouse clicks on certain web elements in a cefsharp browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not my answer: I copied it from @shudel, so thank you @shudel
However, I wanted to make sure that this question got answered.

Using ExecuteScriptAsync will execute JavaScript against the Chrome engine, so you would have to send valid JavaScript to this function. The following code shows how you could start a search using DuckDuckGo

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.WinForms

Public Class Form1
  Private _browser As New ChromiumWebBrowser()


  Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
_browser.Top = 10
_browser.Left = 10
_browser.Width = 600
_browser.Height = 400
Controls.Add(_browser)
  End Sub


  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
    _browser.Load("https://duckduckgo.com/")
'for simplicity just wait until page is downloaded, should be handled by LoadingStateChanged
Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Dim jsScript As String = <js><![CDATA[
    document.all("q").value = "stack overflow";
    document.all("search_button_homepage").click();
                         ]]></js>.Value
_browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScript)
  End Sub


End Class`
```